# Delete a key value pair inside a list with groovy

Tags: groovy

I am new to groovy and trying to delete a key value pair based on the parameter value i get. The json looks like below.

**If i recieve value proj2 from the parameter(projectNameToDelete) it should go and remove the json object for proj2 and also entry in the ProjLink in project test-1 .**

```
[{
    "projectName": "test-1",
    "Team": "WSIT",
    "Num": "1",
    "projLink": [{
        "proj1": "read"
    }, {
        "proj2": "write"
    }],
    "change": "false",
    "repository": "https://github.com/org/repo.git",
    "type": "app",
    "ID": "777321"
},{
    "projectName": "proj2",
    "Team": "WSIT",
    "Num": "1",
    "projLink": [{
        "proj3": "read"
    }, {
        "proj5": "write"
    }],
    "change": "false",
    "repository": "https://github.com/org/repo.git",
    "type": "app",
    "ID": "777321"
}]
```

How can i achieve this using groovy ? I tried the below but it doesn't remove the entry in projLink

```
List<Map<String, String>> toRemove = []

jsonArray.each { jsonObject ->
    def projLink = jsonObject.projLink
    if (projLink instanceof List) {
        projLink.eachWithIndex {map,index ->
            if (map.containsKey(projectNameToDelete)) {
                toRemove << map
                
                println "check the loop"
             
            }
        }
        
       projLink.removeAll(toRemove)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to use a `findResults`-transformation like so:

```
def json = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parseText '''\
[{
    "projectName": "test-1",
    "Team": "WSIT",
    "Num": "1",
    "projLink": [{
        "proj1": "read"
    }, {
        "proj2": "write"
    }],
    "change": "false",
    "repository": "https://github.com/org/repo.git",
    "type": "app",
    "ID": "777321"
},{
    "projectName": "proj2",
    "Team": "WSIT",
    "Num": "1",
    "projLink": [{
        "proj3": "read"
    }, {
        "proj5": "write"
    }],
    "change": "false",
    "repository": "https://github.com/org/repo.git",
    "type": "app",
    "ID": "777321"
}]'''

List projectsExceptFor( json, String projectNameToDelete ) {
  json.findResults{ proj ->
    if( proj.projectName == projectNameToDelete ) return null
    proj.projLink = proj.projLink.findAll{ !it.containsKey( projectNameToDelete ) }
    proj
  }
}

assert projectsExceptFor( json, 'proj2' ).toString() == '[[projectName:test-1, Team:WSIT, Num:1, projLink:[[proj1:read]], change:false, repository:https://github.com/org/repo.git, type:app, ID:777321]]'
assert projectsExceptFor( json, 'proj2' ).size() == 1
assert projectsExceptFor( json, 'proj2' ).first().projLink.size() == 1

assert projectsExceptFor( json, 'test-1' ).toString() == '[[projectName:proj2, Team:WSIT, Num:1, projLink:[[proj3:read], [proj5:write]], change:false, repository:https://github.com/org/repo.git, type:app, ID:777321]]'
assert projectsExceptFor( json, 'test-1' ).size() == 1
assert projectsExceptFor( json, 'test-1' ).first().projLink.size() == 2
```